# return the days in a month that are not in a list

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I've a list of days `list = [1,5,16,29]`

Considering current month `september` and year `2021`

I've a user wise day `df`

```
user_id    day     month   year
  1         1       9      2021 
  1         2       9      2021
  1         6       9      2021
  1        14       9      2021
  1        22       9      2021
  1        18       9      2021
  2         2       9      2021
  2        17       9      2021
  2         3       9      2021
  2        30       9      2021
  2        29       9      2021
  2        28       9      2021
```

How can I get the user wise days of given month and year that are not present in respective users `df['day']` and in the `list`?

Expected result

```
user_id    remaining_days_of_month
   1          3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,17,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,30
   2          4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
```

Comment: Do we know the year too? If it's February the result would different in different years

Comment: @AnanayMital Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, we do know the year too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calendar.monthrange` to get the size of a month, then make a `set` difference

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'day': [1, 2, 6, 14, 22, 18, 2, 17, 3, 30, 29, 28],
                   'month': [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]})

month = df['month'].iloc[0]
values = [1, 5, 16, 29]
days_of_month = set(range(1, 1 + calendar.monthrange(2021, month)[1])).difference(values)

df: pd.DataFrame = df.groupby('user_id')['day'].apply(list).reset_index()
df['day'] = df['day'].apply(lambda cell: set(days_of_month).difference(cell))
```

|  | user_id | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | {3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28} |
| 1 | 2 | {4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27} |

Comment: it has also returned the days present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calendar.monthrange` to get a range of the number of days in a year-month

```
df
```

[image]

```
import calendar

def get_remaining_days(group, lst):
    month = group.month.unique()[0]
    days_to_remove = np.unique(np.concatenate((group.day, lst)))
    lst_of_days = list(range(*calendar.monthrange(2021, month)))
    remaining_days = [i for i in lst_of_days if i not in days_to_remove]
    return remaining_days

lst = [1,5,16,29]

result = df.groupby(by=["user_id", "month"]).apply(lambda x: get_remaining_days(x, lst))
result.name = "remaining_days_of_month"
result = result.to_frame()
result
```

[image]

I made it work for different months and same user. In case you happen to different year too, it won't require much change

Comment: why it is not giving the correct outcome when I use `df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1},
                   'day': {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20, 5: 21, 6: 23, 7: 24, 8: 25, 9: 26, 10: 27, 11: 28, 12:29, 13: 30, 14:31},
                   'month': {0:8, 1:8, 2:8, 3:8, 4:8, 5:8, 6:8, 7:8, 8:8, 9:8, 10:8, 11:8, 12:8, 13:8, 14:8}})` dataframe?

Comment: +continuation `lst = [1,8,15,22,29]`

Comment: I assume, the meaning of `lst_of_days` should give us the entire days. But it is not. It's returning only few days. I couldn't get why it is happening.